# Is it possible to drink alcoholic beverages at Iranian ski resorts?

Tags: winter-sports, alcohol, iran

In [Places you never knew you could ski](http://www.smh.com.au/travel/blogs/miss-snow-it-all/places-you-never-knew-you-could-ski-20130627-2oywy.html), it's implied that you can't drink alcoholic beverages at Iranian ski resorts:

> Visit Tehran in winter and salivate over the Alborz mountain range
>   that dominates the horizon. These snow-laden peaks of over three
>   thousand metres serve up some seriously good powder. Try Dizin resort
>   for three gondolas and twelve chairlifts and mocktails at après. We
>   don't recommend bringing a hip flask.

While I'm aware that Islam disapproves of alcohol, I kind of expected ski resorts to be one of the most likely places to have alcoholic beverages, as they are tourist destinations, rather than residential areas, and potentially ones with foreign non-Muslim tourists visiting.

Is it possible to drink alcoholic beverages at Iranian ski resorts?

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else reading this, I think @HaLaBi was joking.

Comment: As far as no one in authority notices what you are drinking, you will be in no trouble.

Comment: Do it but be careful, it's illegal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [at least one source](http://www.haaretz.com/news/features/skiing-away-from-the-ayatollahs-in-iran.premium-1.495934), yes:

> Despite the rigid separation between men and women on the ski lifts,
>   and often on the courses themselves, visitors revealed that on the
>   mountain slopes, in the hotels and inns, **one could drink alcohol**, hear
>   female singles and mingle freely until all hours of the night. "Just
>   like many other things in Iran, everyone simply turned a blind eye,"
>   Dome explained. As a result, the resorts are an ideal love nest for
>   many Iranian couples.

Answer (score 5):

Even if it's possible, it's **ILLEGAL** and therefore the answer is **NO**. If you want to drink alcohol, just go somewhere else.

Comment: That's a good point, but the OP is asking if it is possible and not if it is legal.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException but we do have a policy of not allowing illegal questions, Dirty does have a valid point

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_in_Iran - only illegal for Muslim citizens of Iran.

Comment: Do you have links and/or personal experience backing this up? I don't want people avoiding a destination because of false information.

Comment: http://wikitravel.org/en/Iran

Comment: @MarkMayo: Yes, but it seems not so clear that this one is illegal.

Comment: As far as I understand Iranian law, Mark is correct in that drinking alcohol in Iran is illegal for Muslim citizens (of Iran), in Iran. But, drinking in public is also illegal, and Haaretz' description of the drinking bout seems to fit that bill. In other words, yes, you can drink if you're not a muslim, but if you don't want to risk unpleasant after effects, do so in private.

Answer (score 1):

Alcohol is legal for Christians in Iran. I guess a Christian tourist can have it as long as it is done in a Christian venue. I feel that changes to this legislation is coming soon and alcohol will be more legalised in Iran for all Iranians due to the failure of prohibition. Alcohol ban is a misinterpretation of Islam anyway as is so much else that is laid out by 'Islamic' regimes (Islam warns about the dangers of it rather than banning it and actually admits a little wine is a good thing: moderate consumption in other words is allowed). I think Iran's current reformist government are seeing the errors in the ways of former governments and reforming a lot of the nonsense.